# Loop through sheet and return each table as a data set

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have written a `function` that will `read` all the `data` from a `spreadsheet`, and then attempt to `parse` each `dataset` into an `array` of `objects`.

Right now, I am able to make it `return` the first `dataset` into an `object` but can't get it to do the same for the other datasets in the `sheet`.

This is what my sheet looks like.

[image]

My overall goal is to grab each section of data if there is a section name in column a, and then place them into the sectionData. Each section would be named by the sectionName. I would like the structure of the array to be something like this:

```
sectionData[sectionName[object[key][value]]sectionName[object[key][name]]]...
```

I have written some code that will loop through and return all the data for the first set, but am having difficulties getting it to return data for the other sets.

```
function getSheetSectionDataTest(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Params"); // get sheet
  var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //get all sheet data
  //var sectionNames = normalizeHeaders(sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues()); //get all data from column A (section names)
  var sectionData = [];
  var section = []; //create empty object for data

  for (var i=0; i<sheetData.length; i++){ //loop through data      
      if (sheetData[i][0] !== ""){ // The loop should stop at each cell in the first column that has a value and run the following code:
        var sectionName = normalizeHeader(sheetData[i]); //return section name found in column A
        //if (sectionName === "types"){
          var headerRow = normalizeHeaders(sheetData[i+1]);
          for (var j = 2; j < sheetData.length; j++) {
              if(sheetData[j][1]!==""){
              var obj = {};
              section.push(obj);   
              for (var rowColumn = 0; rowColumn < headerRow.length; rowColumn++) {

                obj[headerRow[rowColumn]]=sheetData[j][rowColumn+1];
                }              
              }
              else{
                return section; //when the loop runs into an empty cell stop loop and return the data
              }
          }
        //}
      }
    }
};
```

My code will return all the data for 1 section, but not for the others:
[image]

Comment: So the line `var sectionPosition = 11;` is starting your loop on the 12th row? Why not start from the top of the sheet since you are already gating the logic to add data to your array with `if (sectionName === section){`?

Comment: Also, since you only enter the logic to add data to your array when `sectionName === section`, you will only create an obj (row) and add it to your array when you are on a row that only has a header (no data).

Comment: yeah, I started going down a weird path with setting the var sectionPosition. I took some time off to think about the structure and have a new plan. I think it should work. I'll update here when I have something. Thanks for the help.